# WCF Services project on a MVC Project

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment

I have a MVC application and a WCF service on the same Solution Project, but I'm trying to deploy the solution through the MVC application. To accomplish that, I tried modifying the RouteConfig adding the route of the WCF service with the following code:

```
1.   routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("hello", new ServiceHostFactory(),
                typeof(Service1)));
```

But I get this error

```
    cannot convert from 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory' to
 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactoryBase'
```

Could you please help me with this problem?

If I am going in the wrong direction, could you please advise me about the right way to make the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Better not to run the Web app and the Web service in the same Website in IIS, though it is possible through some complex twists.

Generally to make things simple and easy to scale, you may have the Web app and the Web service to run in different Websites of IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution is just to add a reference to `System.ServiceModel` because it contains a type required to cast the second argument.